# How to connect a bend sensor?

Tags: arduino, sensor, ground

I've got bend sensors which I want to connect to analog inputs of an Arduino-board.

Does it matter which of the headers I connect to the GND and which one to the analog inputs?

[image]

The bend Sensors are from Flexpoint. This is The electrical specification
http://23.235.218.36/~flexpoint/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/electronicDesignGuide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Its not exactly clear on which part number that is.  I'm guessing its something similiar to this:

[image: Bend Sensor Extract]

This looks like a variable resistor.  That would mean, you apply voltage and read the drop across the sensor.  If your device has similar performance to the one in the attached chart, you might add a resistor (10K) in series.  Wire one end to +5v, the other end to ground, then measure the voltage in the middle (single wire to an analog input on the arduino)

So my answer to your specific question is I don't think it makes any difference which side is which (anode/cathode behavior of that resistor shouldn't make any difference...)  But I would not wire it the way you are thinking.

Have you checked the specification sheet for your specific device? (Hint: where did you get the part?  Manufacturer's name?  Manufacturers part number?)

Do you really need a voltage divider?  Its not always clear to me on pull up / pull down voltage sense on analog inputs. If I have +5v on one end and ground on the other I know exactly what is going on, I don't have to make assumptions about the inner workings of my input/output card...

Comment: I'm soldering them to an ArduiMu V3+ which has pull up resistors in place for the first four of its six analog inputs.The bend Sensors are from Flexpoint. This is The electrical specification http://23.235.218.36/~flexpoint/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/electronicDesignGuide.pdf

Comment: @Hedge, you should edit your QUESTION to include this info.

Comment: Wow. A good majority of the circuits in that specification document uses a voltage divider.  The do add an opamp for isolation, etc. If it were me, I'd be using one of those circuits for implementation.

Comment: You probably want to choose your own pull-up resistor, unless the one on the board is exactly the right value. Also, for high impedance sources, the A/D will benefit from a capacitor to ground on the analog pin.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the sensor.  Is it a strain-gauge sensor or something exotic?
If it's a strain-gauge, then you probably want to use an instrumentation amplifier with it which means it does not need to be grounded on either of the pins.
If you don't want to use an instrumentation amplifier, the signal may be extremely small and changes will not produce a significant ADC input.

What is the part number and manufacturer of your sensor?